# Shower drain removal with no rubber gasket

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I'm trying to take out a shower pan. I have the drain cover off but am having trouble with the drain itself. Everything online suggests that I need to drill some holes and shimmy the gasket out to free the pan from the floor.

But my drain has no such gasket. It seems like instead there is a soft metal, I can drill into it but have not had much luck loosening.

Does anyone know what this is or how I can remove it? The home Was built in the mid 80s and I believe the shower is original.

[image: drain2]

[image]
Thanks!

Katy

Comment: Katy, you say you are trying to take out a shower pan, which generally refers to the **entire shower floor** including all layers (sloped dry pack, waterproof membrane, sloped floor). Are you really just trying to remove the drain assembly?

Comment: Yes we are removing the entire shower pan, all layers. But the drain assembly is preventing us from doing so.

Comment: The lower half of the drain assembly is embedded in the shower floor, if you intend to replace that drain assembly you will likely need to chisel up cement all around it. They are cemented in (the "cement" is usually **dry pack**, which is sand and cement packed in while damp).

Comment: Do you have access to the plumbing underneath?

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what the drain assembly entails. I plan to replace the top part, the part that seals with the shower floor and is topped with a grate. But The drain itself is fine. I just want to take the shower pan out and replace it. Currently the pan is stuck on the drain, seemingly with this lead filling.

Comment: We have no access to plumbing underneath. It is a second level shower. That would require cutting a hole in first floor ceiling.

Comment: Is that a vinyl or plastic shower floor? I mistakenly thought it was the cement under tile that had been removed.

Comment: It's plastic or fiberglass or similar.

Comment: Do these pictures show holes that you have drilled into the drain base? Post some pictures of the pieces that were removed.

Comment: Yes those are holes we drilled. The pieces that came out looked like corkscrew metal pieces that spiraled around the drill bit.

Comment: Just updated the picture above. It shows one of the little spirals.

Comment: When you said soft metal I thought of a poured lead seal. By the mid 80's almost all drains were plastic pipe. Lead would melt the pipe if poured. But if metal  pipe it is possible. I can't tell from the photo. If it is lead more holes and chisele work will be needed.

Comment: We were thinking lead too. We're pretty sure it's a plastic pvc pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to chisel it out:

[image]

Comment: That picture makes sense, but our drain doesn't look like this. The upper portion of our drain is glued or stuck to the shower pan. We just need to get the pan out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  I ended up drilling and chiseling around in a circle until the floor pan came free.